# How to split letters in .txt file and hold'em with array with c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a txt file. Here is index:

```
1 A D C V K O F R W 
2 Y I J M 
3 Q P 
4 E S Z N L
```

I got the letters in a variable called `string readen[9];`

```
readen[0]` = "A D C V K O F R W";
readen[1]` = "Y I J M";
```

Like this, there are blanks between them. I need to catch all the letters one by one like:

```
readen[0]` = "A";
readen[1]` = "W";
```

(Without blank)

Here is my code:

```
string read;
string readen[9];
char numbers[9];
ifstream file;
file.open("deneme.txt", ios::in);

for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); i++) 
{
    numbers[i] = file.get();
    file.get();
    getline(file,read);
    readen[i] = read;
}
```

As I said, It's like this now --> `readen[0]` = "A D C V K O F R W "

What's the best way to keep it like `readen[0] = 'A' readen[1] = 'D'` ?

Comment: Note [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) please.

Comment: Do you want `readen[0] = "A"` or `readen[0] = 'A'`? These are different things.

Comment: I know they are different but it doesn't matter for now.

Comment: Do you have to store the integers at the beginning of each line? Do you want all letters in a single array (one dimension)?

Comment: Yes, I have to store them seperated. Integers in an array, letters in another array

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cctype>  // std::isalpha()
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream is{ "deneme.txt" };
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::vector<char> letters;

    for (;;) {
        int number;
        int ch;

        // as long as extraction of an integer fails extract characters
        while (!(is >> number) && (is.clear(), (ch = is.get()) != EOF)) {
            if(std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned>(ch)))
                letters.push_back(ch);
        }

        if (!is) break;

        numbers.push_back(number);
    }

    std::cout << "Numbers: ";
    for (auto const &n : numbers)
        std::cout << n << ' ';

    std::cout << "\nLetters: ";
    for (auto const &l : letters)
        std::cout << l << ' ';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

#### Output:

```
Numbers: 1 2 3 4
Letters: A D C V K O F R W Y I J M Q P E S Z N L
```

Comment: Actually I want to keep them like  `char numbers[4];  char letters[19];`  and use them like `char x = letters[5]`    I found a way but I'm doing something wrong. I tried `getline( file, read, ' ')` This way, I thought I could keep letters without blanks but the text was `A D C V K ` and what I get is `ACK`. Program stops and gives error.

Comment: @hoizery "and use them like char x = letters[5]" you can use vectors the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I put in a loop. Everytime, `letters[x] = file.get();   file.get();` First it takes the letter, than ignores 1 characters which is blank.